# Ideal and a direct sum.

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$ and assume $I\oplus M \cong R^{n}$ for some
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can I then conclude $M$ is isomorphic to $J\oplus
>  R^{n-1}$ where $J\oplus I \cong R$?

**Observations/thoughts**

We have $I\oplus 0 \cong I\oplus \overbrace{0 \oplus \dots\oplus 0}^{n-1}$

If we add $I\oplus 0$ with $0\oplus M$ we obtain $I\oplus M$ and thus $M$ should be isomorphic to something in $R^{n}$ such that we obtain $R^{n}$ when we add it with $I\oplus \overbrace{0 \oplus \dots\oplus 0}^{n-1}$.

**For instance**

If $I = 3\mathbb{Z}$, an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$, and $3\mathbb{Z} \oplus M = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ then $M= 4\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Are you taking $\;M\;$ to be an ideal in $\;R\;$ or as a $\;R-$module (and thus also I as a module)?

Comment: $M$ is a $R-$module

Comment: I am pretty sure that the answer is No. There is no reason to expect something like this to be true. Of course for PIDs it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Find a ring in which $I$ is a finitely generated projective ideal which isn't cyclic. For example, you could take any noncyclic ideal in a suitable Dedekind domain.

Then $I$ is a summand of a free module of finite rank, but cannot be a summand of $R$ (because then it would be cyclic.)